Given state $P$, does the set of all forward adiabatic processes and reversed adiabatic processes reach all states in the state space?
Let $A$ be a thermodynamic system and let $\Sigma$ be its state space. By the state postulate, if $A$ has $n$ two-way work channels (i.e. ways in which work can be done both positively and negatively by the system), then $\Sigma$ is $d = n+1$ dimensional.
Now starting from a given point $P\in\Sigma$, quasi-static adiabatic/work-only processes can get you anywhere in a certain subset of $\Sigma$ but not all of $\Sigma$. If we allow both quasi-static and non-quasi-static adiabatic/work-only processes, my understanding is that we can get anywhere in a larger subset $K_{P}$ of $\Sigma$, but still not all of $\Sigma$ by Caratheodory's formulation of second law of thermodynamics (Caratheodory's principle).
I am wondering, if we include both the set of states $P'$ for which $P\rightarrow_{\text{work-only}} P'$ is possible and the set of states $P'$ for which $P'\rightarrow_{\text{work-only}} P$ is possible, do we obtain all of $\Sigma$? If so, is there a proof of this? If not, is there a good counterexample?
To put it another way, let $K_{P}$ be the set of all states accessible starting from $P$ by quasi-static or non-quasi-static adiabatic/work-only processes. Let $L_{P}$ be the set of all states from which you can access $P$ by quasi-static or non-quasi-static adiabatic/work-only processes. Do we have $\Sigma = K_{P}\cup L_{P}$? I'd be interested to know how one can think about this question with some level of rigor.

Are you aware that a quasi-static and not quasi-static adiabatic process cannot connect the same two equilibrium states?

@BobD Honestly no, so if there is a proof it would be preferrable for it to include a proof of this claim. However, if this is too much to ask, then the details don't have to be spelled out; I can do my own research if directed the right path.

Maximal Ideal, of course, you "know" what @Bob_D is talking because a reversible adiabatic process conserves entropy, that is isentropic, while an irreversible adiabatic process increases entropy at every stage of the process while irreversible, so the two starting from the same equilibrium state, say $\mathcal P_0$, can never end in the same equilibrium state, say $\mathcal P_1$.  Unfortunately, this does not help you answering the question you have posed.

The proof is as follows: An non quasi-static adiabatic process between two states  is an irreversible process. Any irreversible process between two states generates entropy. A quasi-static adiabatic process not involving friction is a reversible process. There is no change in entropy for a reversible adiabatic process between two states. Since entropy is a state function the change in entropy between two states is the same regardless of the process. Ergo a reversible and irreversible adiabatic process cannot connect the same two equilibrium states.

[...] I actually do not believe (note the verb "believe" is not  the same as "know") that it is true that any two of its states of an arbitrary thermodynamic system can be connected with some adiabatic irreversible process. Instead, whether it is true or not is  an assumption underlying classical thermodynamic thinking. When it may fail, as some thermodynamicist might argue, are cases that even the concept of "state" may not be classically definable. For example, what would be the appropriate definition of the thermodynamic state of a ferromagnetic material exhibiting hysteresis?

[...] Bridgman generalized the concept of a state and of reversibility for such cases where there is no process consisting of a sequence of conventional states of equilibrium, he talks about restorability not reversibility, but he needs a heat supply make sense of it.

@hyportnex Ok, what Bob_D and you explained is embarrassingly obvious in hindsight; I wasn't thinking too much about the question at the time. Anyways, if my OP claim is an assumption or axiom of some sort, then I suppose just any authoritative source saying this would be enough for an answer (although it seems like this hasn't been widely formally explicated based on your sentiment). I'll eventually look into those generalizations you mentioned since they seem very interesting.

While it is not the same question, and there is no really satisfactory answer to it yet, but it is related to yours and thus you may find it interesting.
